# capture output of table-valued function

Tags: t-sql

Is it possible to capture output of table-valued function? For example, function is defined as follows.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_MyFunction]
(   
    @ItemId INT
)
RETURNS @ReturnTable TABLE 
(
    RowId int primary key NOT NULL,
    Value nvarchar(250) NOT NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- ...
    RETURN;
END
```

I understand you can do `SELECT * FROM ufn_MyFunction(@id)`, but I need to use values from every row of the returned table. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can, you just define a table variable or a temp table and pipe the output from the select into that. Then you can use that in your code.

So, something like this;

```
--Declare some working variables
    declare @t Table ( rowId INT, Value nvarchar(250))
    declare @id int

--Gather the output from the function
    insert into @t
    SELECT * FROM ufn_MyFunction(@id)

-- Use the values
    select *
    from @t
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do SELECT...INTO, Use the table in a join or use [APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx), eg

```
SELECT *
INTO #tmp
FROM [dbo].[ufn_MyFunction] ( 1 )

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[ufn_MyFunction] ( 1 ) f
    INNER JOIN someOtherTable t ON f.RowId = t.rowId

SELECT *
FROM someOtherTable t
    CROSS APPLY [dbo].[ufn_MyFunction] ( t.rowId ) f
```

Comment: This is probably the best approach and use of the TVF.  I use it like a nested select statement when possible; if necessary, i drop it into a temp (RAM or HDD) variable.